# Podspec does not validate without error

Tags: swift, cocoapods, podspec

I'm trying to create private pod.

What I've done:
 * Create and push repo at correct branch
 * Create podspec

Now I'm struggling with podspec validation.

**BKit.podspec**

```
Pod::Spec.new do |s|
  s.name             = 'BKit'
  s.version          = '0.1.0'
  s.summary          = 'This is for myown usage kit'
  s.homepage         = 'https://wdowikowski.pl'
  s.license          = { :type => 'MIT', :file => 'LICENSE' }
  s.author           = { 'Błażej Wdowikowski' => 'blazej@wdowikowski.pl' }
  s.source           = { :git => 'https://url.to.repo', :tag => s.version.to_s }
  s.social_media_url = 'https://twitter.com/the_dudi'
  s.ios.deployment_target = '8.0'
  s.source_files = 'BKit/Classes/**/*'
  s.frameworks = 'UIKit'
  s.dependency 'Cheetah'
  s.dependency 'Decodable'
end
```

After calling `pod repo push BKit BKit.podspec --verbose`  I get

```
//Building log
** BUILD SUCCEEDED **

 -> BKit (0.1.0)
    + WARN  | xcodebuild:  Cheetah/Cheetah/Bezier.swift:44:36: warning: '++' is deprecated: it will be removed in Swift 3
    + WARN  | xcodebuild:  Cheetah/Cheetah/Bezier.swift:44:9: warning: C-style for statement is deprecated and will be removed in a future version of Swift
    + WARN  | xcodebuild:  Cheetah/Cheetah/Cheetah.swift:290:16: warning: '++' is deprecated: it will be removed in Swift 3
    + WARN  | xcodebuild:  Cheetah/Cheetah/Cheetah.swift:295:28: warning: '--' is deprecated: it will be removed in Swift 3
    + WARN  | xcodebuild:  Cheetah/Cheetah/CheetahManager.swift:35:16: warning: '++' is deprecated: it will be removed in Swift 3
    + WARN  | xcodebuild:  Cheetah/Cheetah/CheetahManager.swift:46:65: warning: use of string literal for Objective-C selectors is deprecated; use '#selector' instead

[!] The `BKit.podspec` specification does not validate.

/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-1.0.1/lib/cocoapods/command/repo/push.rb:130:in `block in validate_podspec_files'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-1.0.1/lib/cocoapods/command/repo/push.rb:119:in `each'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-1.0.1/lib/cocoapods/command/repo/push.rb:119:in `validate_podspec_files'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-1.0.1/lib/cocoapods/command/repo/push.rb:64:in `run'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/claide-1.0.0/lib/claide/command.rb:334:in `run'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-1.0.1/lib/cocoapods/command.rb:50:in `run'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-1.0.1/bin/pod:55:in `<top (required)>'
/usr/local/bin/pod:23:in `load'
/usr/local/bin/pod:23:in `<main>'
```

I don't know what I'm doing wrong and I'm not sure at what I should look at.

I'm using **Cocoapods 1.0.1**

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you left in a placeholder for the repo URL.

If you `pod spec lint --verbose` you can see a more detailed error message for why your spec fails, such as `fatal: unable to access 'https://url.to.repo/': Could not resolve host: url.to.repo`. Hope that helps.